# Reading ArrayList via socket giving incorrect size

Tags: java, sockets, arraylist

I'm currently developping a client server game and i'm facing some problem when i'm sending my  ArrayList via a socket.
This is how my application is currently working :

Server launching

Player connect to the server

Server add the player to the players list and start rendering the map and updating it and send the updates to the player connected.

Another player connect

Server add this player and keep doing the same thing.

What i'm doing when the server is sending data to players is just the arraylist of enemies and the arraylist of players, other thing are not important.
So in my player class i got 2 read object, player and enemies. In my server i have 2 write, player and enemies.
My main problem is that when the server is sending the ArrayList of players to the 2 connected player it show me that the size of the ArrayList is 2 (which is normal, here is the log :)

```
[11:12] 2 to 15
[11:12] 2 to 16
[11:12] 2 to 15
[11:12] 2 to 16
[11:12] 2 to 15
[11:12] 2 to 16
```

We can also see that it send it to 2 different id (the connected players).
Now this is what i get when i do this :

```
ArrayList<Player> p = (ArrayList<Player>) this.objIn.readObject();
System.out.println(p.size());
```

For the first connected player i have 1 in size and the second one i have 2. That basicly mean the one player is lost in the transaction. If i add another player (so it makes 3), the same thing happen, the first player connected will have an ArrayList with a size of 1, the second one a size of 2 and the last one a size of 3.
Here is my sendObject code :

```
    if(this.players.size() > 0) {
        for(GestionPlayer gp : this.players) {
            gp.sendPlayer(this.level.players);
        }
    }
```

And the sendPlayer method :

```
public void sendPlayer(ArrayList<Player> players) {
    try {
        this.objectOut.writeObject(players);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Do you guys know if i'm doing something wrong ?

Thanks !

PS : I'm aware that sending Object with socket is not realy good (better to send raw data), but i don't want to argue that here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to investigate `ObjectOutputStream.reset()`. 
Otherwise you will keep reading the same `Object` with the same values over and over again.